# Can I use module-info.java if target level is 8?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system, module-info, multi-release-jar

I know that module-info.java is recognized by jdk9+

I wonder however whether module-info.java can still be used in combination with target level 8.

E.g. I want my library to be used in java9+ projects, which will recognize it as a module exporting specific packages, but also be used in java8 projects as a plain jar file.

Comment: Yes, you can. There are various guides on the net showing that's possible.

Comment: Such a guide, which I personally find clear, is the following: https://blog.codefx.org/tools/multi-release-jars-multiple-java-versions/

Answer (score 5):

[The Multi-Release JAR files](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238) are meant for the exact same purpose itself.

> In a *JDK that does not support MRJARs*, ***only the classes and resources
> in the root directory will be visible***, and the two packagings will be
> indistinguishable.
>
> In a *JDK that does support MRJARs*, the *directories
> corresponding to any later Java platform release would be ignored*; it
> would search for classes and resources first in the Java
> ***platform-specific directory corresponding to the currently-running
> major Java platform release version***, *then search those for lower
> versions, and finally the JAR root*.
>
> On a Java 9 JDK, it would be as if
> there were a JAR-specific class path containing first the version 9
> files, and then the JAR root; on a Java 8 JDK, this class path would
> contain only the JAR root.

For an example of this based on Maven, take a look at this - [maven-jep238](https://github.com/hboutemy/maven-jep238).